# Layered Navigation has different Links to the main Navi

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, rwd-theme

in a shop we have the usual main Navigation, which outputs the url as a clean url-rewrite url, eg: `/category-one/sub-category-one/`

Now if I click into the first category /category-one and use the layered navigation in the sidebar to get to the sub-category, the URL Link is written as:

`/category-one?cat=2` rather than the clean urls version from the main menu:
 `/category-one/sub-category-one/`

**Why is this and how do I change this?**

In the code the url is rendered using:

`echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)`

and in the main navi it is rendered with:

`$child->getUrl()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you aren't actually viewing that category, you are view `category-one` filtering the products by only products that are in `sub-category-one`. Whilst this might sound like a pedantic difference, there are multiple reasons they aren't the same thing. Layout handles applied will be those matching `category-one` not `sub-category-one` for example. The same applies for all settings/attributes that can be modified on a category level, such as theme. If `sub-category-one` wasn't a category with `is_anchor` enabled, then by your approach, clicking it would mean the layered navigation disappears, whereas it doesn't with the current implementation.

There is no core functionality to support what you are trying to achieve, however you could potentially modify the code if you are happy with the above effects. The simplest way would probably be to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item::getUrl` and do something like:

```
if ($this->getFilter()->getRequestVar() === 'cat') {
    return Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($this->getValue())->getUrl();
}
return parent::getUrl();
```

Though I doubt this is massively efficient.

Comment: Thanks @Cags! I wasn't thinking straight, else I would have realised that it is a filter and not a link to the category. Doh!